# Error while testing code generation in Dart: Builder failed to write asset

Tags: dart, flutter

I have create a Dart (Dart v2) code generator to detect annotations of type Cooper.

The generator looks like this:

```
class CooperGenerator extends GeneratorForAnnotation<Cooper> {
  @override
  Future<String> generateForAnnotatedElement(
      Element element, ConstantReader annotation, BuildStep buildStep) async {
    final name = annotation?.peek("implementationClassName")?.stringValue ?? "CooperApi";
    return "class $name {}";
  }
}
```

I am writing unit tests to verify that my Generator works as expected. Looks like this:

```
import 'package:build/build.dart';
import 'package:test/test.dart';
import 'package:build_test/build_test.dart';
import 'package:source_gen/source_gen.dart';
import 'package:cooper_generator/cooper_generator.dart';

void main() {
  group('CooperGenerator', () {
    test('generates implementation for classes annotated with @Cooper',
        () async {
      final builder = PartBuilder([CooperGenerator()], '.g.dart');
      await testBuilder(builder, _inputs, outputs: _output);
    });
  });
}

final _output = {
  "jorge|lib/coop.g.dart": '''
// GENERATED CODE - DO NOT MODIFY BY HAND

part of 'coop.dart';

// **************************************************************************
// CooperGenerator
// **************************************************************************

class CooperImplementation {}
          '''
};

final _inputs = <String, String>{
  'cooper|lib/cooper.dart': _cooperSource,
  'jorge|lib/coop.dart': _classToGenerate,
};

const String _classToGenerate = r'''
    import 'package:cooper/cooper.dart';
    @Cooper("CooperImplementation")
    abstract class CooperContract {}
''';

const String _cooperSource = r'''
class Cooper {
  final String implementationClassName;

  const Cooper(this.implementationClassName);
}
''';
```

The code works perfectly fine, and it generates the code I am expecting. However, when running the unit tests, I am getting the following error, and I can't understand why:

```
ERROR: Expected: contains AssetId:<jorge|lib/coop.g.dart>
Actual: ?:[]
Builder failed to write asset jorge|lib/coop.g.dart

package:test                                    expect
package:build_test/src/test_builder.dart 49:7   checkOutputs.<fn>
dart:collection                                 __InternalLinkedHashMap&_HashVMBase&MapMixin&_LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach
package:build_test/src/test_builder.dart 41:13  checkOutputs
package:build_test/src/test_builder.dart 140:3  testBuilder
===== asynchronous gap ===========================
dart:async                                      _AsyncAwaitCompleter.completeError
package:build_test/src/test_builder.dart        testBuilder
===== asynchronous gap ===========================
dart:async                                      _asyncThenWrapperHelper
package:build_test/src/test_builder.dart        testBuilder
test/generator_test.dart 12:13                  main.<fn>.<fn>
```

Does anyone know why this is giving me this error?